# Trouble With HttpsURLConnection Authentication in Android

Tags: java, php, android, apache, authentication

I am attempting to authenticate from the android app. It is an apache basic auth. It seems, through error logs, that the webpage is taking what is after the URL as the username for some reason? Any thoughts on this? Here is my code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://website.com/");
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " +
                    Base64.encode("user:pass".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.connect();
```

If i add a path the the website, it tells me that that path is not a user. Without a path it says that "/" is not a user.

I have also tried doing user:pass@website.com which didn't work either.

Comment: You can debug HTTP issues with a network protocol analyzer like tcpdump, ethereal, or ssldump (if you must use HTTPS). I've found that looking at packets is often easier than trying to configure your HTTP client's debug logging.

Comment: This error is from the websites error logs.

Comment: Understood, but the log isn't telling you much. To find out what's actually happening, it would help to see the raw HTTP request, and you can do that with a network protocol analyzer.